# using C# with PIG on HDInsight Azure

Tags: c#, apache-pig, azure-hdinsight

I am working with HDInsight .NET SDK to use C# sdk with pig. I am getting error when specifying the c# application path.

here's how am defining the C# app in pig script

```
DEFINE pigudf `PigUDF.exe` SHIP('wasb://book@storage.blob.core.windows.net/PIG/app/PigUDF.exe');
```

am getting error "invalid ship specification" 'wasb://bookstore@storage160203122480.blob.core.windows.net/PIG/app/PigUDF.exe' doesn't exists, however PigUDF.exe does exists at the given path.

If I run the same query from HDInsight cluster console with both pig script file and c# app stored locally on cluster, it runs successfully.. i.e the below works on hdinsight cluster console

```
DEFINE pigudf `PigUDF.exe` SHIP('C:/PigUDF.exe');
```

where pigudf.exe is locally stored on cluster.

I even tried running it through HDInsight tools for visual studio, but I get same error.

Any help here will be appreciated.

thanks,

Saleem

Answer (score 0):

Try using http:// instead of wasb://.  The wasb protocol is used to access Windows Azure blob storage.

```
DEFINE pigudf `PigUDF.exe` SHIP('http://book@storage.blob.core.windows.net/PIG/app/PigUDF.exe');
```

Comment: The file is in blob storage and I had to access the blob storage. When I execute in on HDInsight cluster console, I give the path of the local storage. I tried, however this didn't work. I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your udf to local, update its permissions, ship it, and eventually remove it

```
fs -copyToLocal wasb://<container>@account/udf.exe
sh cacls udf.exe /E /G <group>:F
define myUdf `udf.exe`ship('udf.exe')
-- run your computation...
sh del udf.exe
```